# setuptools bdist_msi installing dependencies

Tags: setuptools, setup.py

I am using the [`bdist_msi` command](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/builtdist.html#creating-built-distributions) in setup tools to build an MSI for my package. Is it possible to build and bundle the package's dependencies (i.e. those listed in `install_requires`) into the msi as well?